# mongod command crashes with message

Tags: mongodb

I have installed MongoDB 3.0.4 . When i execute command "mongod" it crashes with message "Mongod.exe has stopped working". Here is problem details

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   mongod.exe
Application Version:    0.0.0.0
Application Timestamp:  557ef9c9
Fault Module Name:  MSVCR120.dll
Fault Module Version:   12.0.21005.1
Fault Module Timestamp: 524f83ff
Exception Code: c000001d
Exception Offset:   0000000000092bc3
OS Version: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.48
Locale ID:  1033
Additional Information 1:   fd3b
Additional Information 2:   fd3bb24d4274b34ca613c6f4e63ceb13
Additional Information 3:   3204
Additional Information 4:   3204b56578b4c221b1569b71b387eb68
```

I am using Windows 7 64 bit operating system. Why this problem ???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the exact issue with current version 3.0.6 of mongodb. I uninstalled it and installed 2.6.11 verson. And it worked! For your information I am also using Win 7 OS 64 bit.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem when launching Worckbench.
I just installed the [Visual C++ Redistributable Packages for Visual Studio 2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40784) and the problem was solved.

Comment: just download and install it but nothing changes

Answer (score -1):

Installing Windows 7 SP1 fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

I have installed MongoDB 3.2.10 using Windows Server 2008 R2 x64, and it was the same problem with you.
The solution is upgrade the OS to SP1.